# How do I get the next line in an output for an array to continue off of the previous array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

how do I get the next line in an output for an array to continue off of the previous array?
this is what I have tried so far

```
let myArray = ([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]])

for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
myArray.map(i => ++i);
console.log(myArray)
}
```

this is my output for the code I have tried:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

but this is the solution I want:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]

[[8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14]]

[[15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21]]

[[22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28]]

[[29], [30]
```

I'm new to this so please go easy on me if I'm getting a simple solution wrong.

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `map`... I think you want `myArray = myArray.map(([i] => [i + myArray.length])`, and you should `console.log(myArray)` before you modify it

Answer (score 1):

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function. So you have to re-assign the value back to the variable.

```js
let myArray = ([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]])

for(var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
    console.log(myArray)
    // create a new array and map it to the array item
    myArray = myArray.map(i => [i[0] + myArray.length]);
}
```